# Log4j2 cannot expand system property user.home

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j2 in a spring boot app for logging.

When I set the absolute path in *fileName*, I can see the log file is being created.
However, *user.home* is not working and this makes the config system dependent.

What am I doing wrong here?

*log4j2.yaml*:

```
Configutation:
  name: Default


  Appenders:

    RollingFile:
      - name: RollingFile_Appender
        fileName: ${user.home}/deepscan.log
        filePattern: "deepscan.log.%i.gz"
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
        Policies:
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 20 MB
        DefaultRollOverStrategy:
          max: 10

  Loggers:

      Logger:
        - name: com.home.test
          additivity: false
          level: debug
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: RollingFile_Appender
              level: info
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the lookup method according to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html

So this would be

```
fileName: ${sys:user.home}
```